# PHP pagination in php application

Tags: php, pagination

I use the PHP-MVC (https://github.com/panique/mini) for small projects, mostly just for structure as I like the design pattern but I'm struggling to implement a pagination class I always use into it. I use the following: https://daveismyname.com/pagination-with-a-php-class-bp#.VNzLzZ2sWWA

I load the class via the application.php basically a bootstrap file to load the class and a few others. In my model I have the following:

```
    public function pagi()
{

    $pages = new Paginator('30','p');

    //get number of total records
    $sql = 'SELECT count(id) FROM albums';
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $total = $row[0];

    //pass number of records to
    $pages->set_total($total); 

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM albums '.$pages->get_limit();
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $data = $query->fetchAll();

    //create the page links
    echo $pages->page_links();

    return $data;
}
```

In my controller I'm calling the following:

```
$albums_model = $this->loadModel('AlbumsModel');
$albums = $albums_model->pagi();
```

And in my view (for debug purposes) i'm simply looping over this:

```
<?php 
print_r($albums); 
?>
```

Now the part that's bugging me and I'm not sure how to do is this part in the model:

```
echo $pages->page_links();
```

Obviously I shouldn't be echoing output directly from a model anyway but I'm unsure of the best way to implement this into the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay I've figured it out now, I just return a multidimensional array like so:

```
return array('pages' => $pages, 'data' => $data);
```

Then in the controller pick these arrays up and separate them into two variables which are passed to the view:

```
$arrays = $albums_model->pagi();
$albums = $arrays['data'];
$pages = $arrays['pages'];
```

And then simply loop over or echo out when needed.